# How to prevent jQuery UI slider handles overlapping?

Tags: jquery-ui

Using jQuery-UI 1.7, I have integrated slider. Everything is working fine, But slider's handles are overlapping each other while dragging. How can i prevent this.

You can see my ui slider here

Default view:

[image]

Overlapped view:

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can accomplish this by detecting an overlap in a `slide` event handler and returning false to prevent the slide from occurring.  Example:

```js
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ( ui.values[ 0 ] + 20 ) >= ui.values[ 1 ] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body { padding: 50px; }
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Note that in this example the value of `20` is simply hardcoded based on the width of the handle.  Per your use case you'll have to change that to whatever makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. If you drag the slider, They are overlapping each other. That's my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if ( (ui.values[0] + 55) >= ui.values[1] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });​
</script>
```