# jQuery UI Slider. intersection sliders and the inversion range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I apologize for my English and ask to help in the problem.

I need to allow the intersection the sliders and invert with a range of.
Make it clearer that it is drawn to:

[image]

current code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeka5555/d5wUS/)

Comment: Made himself http://jsfiddle.net/jeka5555/d5wUS/9/

Comment: [I was having the same issue and the following post had answer:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754778/how-to-prevent-jquery-ui-slider-handles-overlapping