# How do you create a slider with two handles that also prevent overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want a slider that changes the value of the input box when it is dragged, but when values are entered manually into the input box, the slider also reflects that.

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="10" />
        <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="1" value="90" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="slider"></div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        values: [10, 90],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    });
});
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/

But I need the handlers of the slider to bounce off each other, when they are being dragged into each other. In other words, the right handler should not be able to go to the left of the handler.

Comment: If the second fiddle does what you want, what's your question?

Comment: 2nd fiddle lacks almost every ability that the first fiddle have.

Comment: Specifically, what abilities would you be referring to?

Comment: Link to 2nd fiddle is removed since it might cause confusing, but here is the link to it http://jsfiddle.net/SP5VQ/

Comment: The 2nd fiddle when you manually type in numbers into the input box, it doesnt change on the slider

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent jquery ui slider handles overlaping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754778/how-to-prevent-jquery-ui-slider-handles-overlaping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/1096/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        values: [10, 90],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if ( ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1] ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                    $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a relatively good fix, but I was thinking more of making the handler push each other. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/SP5VQ/